# очистка потока ввода в Linux

Tags: c++

Как  правильно очищать поток ввода от ошибок в Linux? cin.clear() не работает.

Comment: `cin.clear()` скорее всего работает, а вот символ вызвавший ошибку остался в потоке.

Comment: clear сбрасывает флаги ошибок, он не занимается очисткой потока.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

//...

std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()  );
std::cin.clear();
```