# Чтение чисел из файла, невалидное состояние цикла

Tags: c++

Читаю таким образом, где  `file` мой объект класса `<ifstream>`, цикл перейдет в невалидное состояние, если поймаю символ, как считать из файла все, что подходит по типу, а не встать колом?

```
                int n, count = 0;
                while (file >> n) 
                {

                    ++count;
                }
```

Пы.Сы. Если число в файле больше размера инта, как его обойти? То есть тоже не считывать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454210/очистка-потока-ввода-в-linux думаю. Что в вопрос Линукс - не смотрите.

Comment: @pavel, проверять во вложенном каждый символ из потока?

Comment: нет, читать как читается, если произошла ошибка выполнить эти действия и продолжить.

Comment: @LokenGarvel', ofstream или всё же ifstream?

Comment: @DenSDS, ifstream)